# Using Spiderable in meteor duplicates head content before displaying html in body tags

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, phantomjs

I have been trying to figure out this strange problem I am having with my meteor site. I first thought it was a problem with Google not indexing but have investigated further to the point that I think I may be causing some sort of problem with the Spiderable package.

I am using meteor version 1.1.0.3. With the spiderable package installed as well as gadicohen:phantomjs, as recommended by [meteorpedia](http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/spiderable/).

The issue I am running into is that instead of creating a nice html page for Google it seems to duplicate the default head code multiple times, within a new head tag, before ending the new head tag and displaying the body and html content. The code is quite long so you can see the issue by visiting [suleimanholdings.com?_escaped_fragment_=](http://suleimanholdings.com?_escaped_fragment_=) and viewing the page source.

I'm hoping someone may have an idea or suggestion of what I can do to stop the duplicating and correctly create an html version for google to crawl.

**EDIT**

The following is the code I use, with each template being fed between the body tags

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Suleiman Holdings</title>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico?v=2">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-62610011-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

**EDIT 2**

```
This is the template code from the homepage:

    <template name="home">
    {{> nav}}


    <div style="overflow:hidden">
    <div id="main" role="main">
        <section class="slider">
            <div class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <div class="slider-bottom"></div>
                    <li style="background-image: url('/one-tech2.jpg');">
                        <div class="news" style="background-image : linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, .6) 20%);">
                            <h1>
                                One Technology Place
                            </h1>
                            <div class="news2">
                                <h2>
                                    Acquired: February 2015
                                </h2>
                                <p>
                                    Suleiman Holdings acquires the Nebraska Technology Park’s flagship office in a 3.3M cash transaction.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider-bottom">
                            <div class="line" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:10px;"></div>
                            <h3>
                                2015
                            </h3>
                            <div class="line" style="margin-left:80px"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li style="background-image: url('/12thQ-inside2.jpg');">
                        <div class="news" style="background-image : linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, .6) 20%);">
                            <h1>
                                University of Nebraska
                            </h1>
                            <div class="news2">
                                <h2>
                                    Leased: January 2015
                                </h2>
                                <p>
                                    Suleiman Holdings welcomes the University of Nebraska College of Journalism and Mass Communications to Downtown Lincoln
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider-bottom">
                            <div class="line" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:10px;"></div>
                            <h3>
                                2015
                            </h3>
                            <div class="line" style="margin-left:80px"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li style="background-image: url('/interns.jpg');">
                        <div class="news" style="background-image : linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255, 0), rgba(255,255,255, .7) 20%);">
                            <h1>
                                Summer Internship Series
                            </h1>
                            <div class="news2">
                                <h2>
                                    Starting Summer 2015
                                </h2>
                                <p>
                                    Suleiman Holdings welcomes three interns to Lincoln for a summer of acquisitions and accounting.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slider-bottom">
                            <div class="line" style="margin-left:0px; margin-right:10px;"></div>
                            <h3>
                                2015
                            </h3>
                            <div class="line" style="margin-left:80px"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                            <div class="line"></div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
    {{> footer}}
    </template>
```

This is the code for the nav template

```
<template name="nav">

    <div class="logobox">
        <div class="mainnavwrap">
            <div class="menumain">
                <a href="/">
                    <div style="position:absolute; height:50px; width:150px; top:0px; z-index:5500; margin-left:60px;"></div>
                </a>
                <ul style="/*position:absolute; width:400px; right:0;*/">

                    <!--<li><a href="private-equity">PRIVATE EQUITY</a></li>
                    <li><a href="real-estate">REAL ESTATE</a></li>-->
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="toggleMobile">
            <span class="menu1"></span>
            <span class="menu2"></span>
            <span class="menu3"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="logo2">
            <a href="home"><img src="/logo-black.png"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="mobileMenu">
            <ul>
                <a href="home">
                    <li>HOME</li>
                </a>

                <a href="real-estate">
                    <li>REAL ESTATE</li>
                </a>
                <a href="private-equity">
                    <li>PRIVATE EQUITY</li>
                </a>
                <a href="about"><li>ABOUT</li></a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And this is the code for the footer template

```
<template name="footer">
    <div class="footer">
        <span class="copyright">&copy; Copyright 2015 Suleiman Holdings</span>

        <div class="legal">
            <span style="margin-left:20px; font-size:12px;">
                <a href="about" style="margin-right:10px;">About</a>
                <a href="press" style="margin-right:10px;">Press</a>
                <!--<a href="careers" style="margin-right:10px;">Careers</a>-->
                <label class="btn" for="modal-1">Contact</label>
                <a href="legal">Legal</a>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>


    <input class="modal-state" id="modal-1" type="checkbox"/>

    <div class="modal">
        <label class="modal__bg" for="modal-1"></label>

        <div class="modal__inner">
            <label class="modal__close" for="modal-1"></label>

            <div class="contact">
                <div class="con-logo"><img src="/contact-logo.jpg"></div>
                <p>
                    4665 Innovation Drive
                    <br>
                    Lincoln, Nebraska 68521
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>
```

Comment: I don't think spiderable would do that by itself. It must be something in your code. Probably browsers just fix that for you, but the problem is still there. Please show your code. Do you perhaps use `head` tags in a template?

Comment: I assumed it would be something on my end rather than spiderables since it seems to work so well for so many other people, I edited my question to include the code I believe you asked for.

Comment: this is still not enough information. We'll need to see the templates, too. Did you know that meteor collects *all* head tags in *all* html files everywhere in your project and create one big header out of it? Also, make sure you don't have `head` anywhere within a template.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I'm sorry my understanding is that you wanted to see all of the code with the the head in it. The code I added above is the only time a head tag is used so that is why I didn't include every template as well. I do understand that they all would get compiled which is why I only used the head tag once. I am adding the homepage's template code now, or do you really think you need every single template?

Comment: hm, ok thanks. nothing suspicious in those templates. And the head is just in a single html file in your project somewhere?

Comment: @ChristianFritz That's right, the head is just in the one spot.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **iron router** you need to remove the `body` tag and the `head` tag from your html master template ( main || masterLayout || layout ) and leave just the `{{> yield}}`

Example:

```
<template name="masterLayout">
    {{> navbar}}
    <div class="container">
    {{> yield}}   
    </div>
</template>
```